# Contained UISplitView not sending delegate methods

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

`UISplitView` has the following delegate methods that aid modification of layout during rotation:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc 
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController 
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
       forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc;

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc 
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController 
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
```

these methods are being respectively invoked by methods private to `UISplitView`, named `_viewControllerHiding:` and `_updateMasterViewControllerFrame`.  Both of these are being invoked directly from the top of the event loop, apparently with a delayed invocation.

But, if I place my own view controller as window's root (you can't place a split view controller in a navigation controller), and place the split view subordinate to it, the delegate methods are not being sent appropriately.  (Actually, one is sent on `viewDidLoad`, but none on rotations.)  The hiding of the master view still occurs, but no delegate love to aid in layout (managing the popover/bar items).

I have tried forwarding the following view controller methods to the contained split view, but they aren't triggering it.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

Anyone have any insight on how to get these UISplitView delegate methods to fire?  Preferably not private API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Combined View Controller Interfaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1) and you'll see that split view controllers aren't supposed to be contained inside any other type of view controller. You're breaking that rule by putting one inside your own view controller, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work well.

Comment: yes i was pushing the design specs a bit, thankfully they are abstracting/formalizing container controllers for 5.0

Comment: i redesigned the code entirely, placing a "manager" responsible for swapping out the root controller of the window (and transitioning between them reasonably) - the manager was in no way related to the view/view controller hierarchy, other than manipulating it